# how to send the selected list value from autocomplete and sent it along with another autocomplete jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am getting values in Autocomplete jQuery, and i am getting alert of the particular item which i selects from the list, so far every thing is good

what i am actually trying to do is that, in first autocomp list i am selecting author names from a table in database,

in the seconf autocomp list i need to populate the corresponding list of books of that particular author,

Here are my codes of autocomp authornames

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $("#tag").autocomplete({
                    source:'autocomplete.php',
                    minLength:1,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
    var label = ui.item.label;
    var value = ui.item.value;
    //alert(label);
    alert(value);
                    }
                });
            });
```

and here is my code for autocopmlete list for book related to the selected author

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#qid").autocomplete
  ({
   source:"autocompletequote.php",
   minLength:1,
   data: { postcode: $('#tag').val() },
   select: function (event, ui) 
   {
    var label = ui.item.label;
    var value = ui.item.value;
    //alert(label);
    alert(value);

   }


});
 });
```

i tried this way

and tried to catch it it autocompletequote.php via

```
$_GET['postcode']
```

but i dont think it is recieving any values there

what am i doing wrong?

please help

Comment: Do you enter your autocompletequote.php script?

Comment: yes ofcorse, and i am getting results for the first query,
for the second query, the value i am passing is not recieving in autocompletequote

Comment: Check the element with id = tag after the firstselection and see if there is any value in this element?

Comment: yes there lies the problem, i am getting value in value variable in the first jquery, i need to pass that value in second query, how to do this?

Comment: That element isn't empty?